# Ruby Interpolation Results in Out-of-Order Output

Tags: ruby, interpolation, puts

New to Ruby here and trying to output the contents of an instance for a class I've created. I don't think it should matter, but known_var in the following is being retrieved from an array. The line I am running is simply:

```
for known_var in @known_variables
  puts "known_var is #{known_var}"
```

The result I am getting is consistently in the format:

```
resistance = 2200 Ohmsknown_var is #<Variable:0x000001e21047f920>
```

The class does have a customized to_s definition, which why the first chunk is formatted as it is:

```
def to_s
    if @value == nil
    print "#@full_name = 0"
    else print "#@full_name = #@value #@unit"
    end
end
```

However, I'm not sure why this is showing up before the "known_var is" part of the string. It looks similar if I specify:

```
puts "known_var is #{known_var}"
```

minus the Variable part, which makes sense:

```
amperage = 12 Aknown_var is
```

Is there something that should be done differently if I want it to just output the text in the order it's provided in puts: "known_var is XXXXXX"?

I've run some searches to see if I can find an explanation (without luck so far). I can work around it by splitting the puts into two separate lines, but that's not what I'm looking to do, and more importantly, I want to understand why puts is ordering things in the way it is here.

Comment: Ruby has a `for` statement but it's hardly ever used in practice. The more idiomatic form here is `@known_variables.each do |known_var|`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`puts` is not ordering anything. Let us construct a toy example, and then trace through the execution.

```
class Foo
  def to_s
    print "[In to_s]"
    "42"
  end
end

def test
  foo = Foo.new
  puts "foo is #{foo}"
end
```

Just as you noted, running `test` prints `[In to_s]foo is 42`. How?

- in `test`: a new `Foo` is constructed, and assigned to `foo`
- The string `"foo is #{foo}"` needs to be evaluated in order to pass it as an argument to the `puts` function
- To do that, `foo.to_s` needs to be evaluated
- `to_s` prints `[In to_s]` without a newline (because that is what `print` does, unlike `puts`)
- `to_s` returns `"42"` (Ruby functions return the last evaluated expression, unless an explicit `return` statement is executed)
- Now that we know what `foo.to_s` evaluates to (`"42"`), we can evaluate `"foo is #{foo}"`: it is `"foo is 42"`
- `puts` gets executed, with `"foo is 42"` as its argument
- `"foo is 42"` is output, right after the `[In to_s]` that was output before.

As Rajagopalan notes, `to_s` should create a string representation of your object; it is not supposed to output anything. Once I have the string representation, I can decide whether to print it or not. For example, it would be very weird if `bar = foo.to_s` outputs anything — I just want to store the text representation of `foo` into a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, the docs on [`to_s`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s) are quite misleading in that regard: _"The default `to_s` **prints** the object’s class and an encoding of the object id"_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Stefan That is unfortunate indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid printing statements within the to_s method; instead, consider the updated to_s method below.

```
def to_s
  if @value == nil
    "#@full_name = 0"
  else
    "#@full_name = #@value #@unit"
  end
end
```